# Creating Browser Enabled Form Without Using InfoPath

Tags: development, visual-studio, form

I'm relatively new and inexperienced with SharePoint 2010 development and I have a question that may sound a bit strange.  I'd like to be able to create a Form Library that has entries opens into a browser enabled form.  I've been doing just this with InfoPath 2010 for the past few months, but I was just wondering if there was a way to create a browser enabled form for a Form Library without having to use InfoPath at all.

Also, would it also be possible to select an entry a library or a list and have it open and display its data for editing in a webpart or site page instead of a browser enabled form?

Any help and advice is more than welcome.  Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a HTML page (or use a content editor webpart) and use the JavaScript client side object model (CSOM) to read and write data to and from SharePoint.  You wouldn't really use a form library for this, probably just a normal list would be fine.

Using SharePoint Designer you can customize the display, edit, and new pages for a list or library either by creating a new page with a webpart on it and changing that page to be the edit page or editing the current edit page to include your webpart on it.  That might help you accomplish part 2 of your question above.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee537247(v=office.14).aspx